# openssl support for DTLS v1.2

Tags: openssl, dtls

I have the openssl version pre-installed in Ubuntu 14.04

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

This is the latest one available in Ubuntu.
Now the issue is after `SSL_library_init();` I called for `DTLSv1_2_client_method();` when I compiled the code it showed :

```
DTLS_test.c:20:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     method = DTLSv1_2_client_method();
            ^
/tmp/ccRUlnEu.o: In function `init_lib':
DTLS_test.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `DTLSv1_2_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if I change to `method = DTLSv1_client_method();`
It only shows warning related to cast

```
DTLS_test.c:20:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     method = DTLSv1_2_client_method();
            ^
```

The code snippet follows :

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/dtls1.h>
#include "DTLS_test.h"

void init_lib (void) {

    if(SSL_library_init()) {
        printf("\n[OK] SSL library initialized");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n[ERROR] SSL library initiate FAILED !");
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_METHOD *method = NULL;
    method = DTLSv1_2_client_method();
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if(ctx != NULL) {
        printf("\n[OK] SSL Method created");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n[ERROR] SSL Method FAILED !");
        exit(0);
    }
}
void main (void) {
    init_lib ();
    printf("\n");
}
```

I downloaded openssl source from git as well and installed but the openssl version didn't change. And I was not able to compile. Anyone suggest any fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTLSv1.2 is not supported in OpenSSL 1.0.1. You need to have 1.0.2 for that.

Which version did you attempt to install from git? By default, when installing yourself, OpenSSL will install to "/usr/local/ssl". It will not replace the system version of OpenSSL, so you will need to ensure you are using the corrent include/library paths - otherwise you will just pick up the old system version.

Compile with:

```
 gcc DTLS_test.c -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -o DTLS_test -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: I downloaded 1.0.2 from openssl and installed it.
Now openssl version command shows me : OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015 But the problem is still there. I compiled with -lssl and -lcrypto

Comment: I upgraded further to OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre2-dev  xx XXX xxxx but the problem is still there
gcc DTLS_test.c -I/usr/local/ssl/ -lssl -lcrypto -o DTLS_test

Comment: Try: gcc DTLS_test.c -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -o DTLS_test -lcrypto -lssl

Comment: Oops. Sorry. That should have been: gcc DTLS_test.c -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -o DTLS_test -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: @Zim I've seen that you accepted this answer, does that mean that the last comment worked? Matt, could you integrate it in your answer if it did?